# how to save jupyter output into a pdf file

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I am doing some data science analysis on jupyter and I wonder how to get all the output of my cell saved into a pdf file ?

thanks

Comment: I am not aware of a solution to save the output of a particular cell into a pdf file. However, you can run an entire jupyter notebook and save all of the input cells, and their corresponding output into a html (not pdf as you asked) using the [runipy package](https://github.com/paulgb/runipy): `runipy MyNotebook.ipynb --html report.html`

Answer (score 4):

When I want to save a Jupyter Notebook I right click the mouse, select print, then change Destination to Save as PDF. This does not save the analysis outputs though. So if I want to save a regression output, for example, I highlight the output in Jupyter Notebook, right click, print, Save as PDF. This process creates fairly nice looking documents with code, interpretation and graphics all-in-one. There are programs that allow you to save more directly but I haven't been able to get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the following at the moment:

```
The version of the notebook server is: 5.4.0
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 13:40:45) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

With this notebook server, you can select File -> Download as -> and select PDF as LaTeX. Alternatively, you can also choose File -> Preview and print to your favorite PDF virtual printer.